# Add values from array into Realm database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have my Device class defined as such:

```
class Device: Object {   
    dynamic var asset_tag = ""

}
```

I have an array like this `["43", "24", "23", "64"]`

and I would like to loop through the array and add each one into the asset_tag attribute of the Device entity in Realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array in Realm you use List. According to Realm's docs, List is the container type in Realm used to define to-many relationships. It goes on to say, "Properties of List type defined on Object subclasses must be declared as let and cannot be dynamic." This means you need to define an entirely separate object to create a list in Realm, there are no native types that will allow you to do something like

```
    let assetTagList = List<String>().
```

You need to create an AssetTags object and make a list of it in your Device object as follows:

```
    class AssetTags: Object {
        dynamic var stringValue = ""
    }

    class Device: Object {   

        var asset_tags: [String] {
    get {
        return _assetTags.map { $0.stringValue }
    }
    set {
        _assetTags.removeAll()
        _assetTags.append(objectsIn: newValue.map({ AssetTags(value: [$0]) }))
    }
}
        let _assetTags = List<AssetTags>()

        override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
           return ["asset_tags"]
        }
    }
```

Now you can do this to add asset tags to Device.

```
    //adding asset tags
    let realm = try! Realm()


    try! realm.write {
        let device = Device()
        device.asset_tags = ["1", "2"]
        realm.add(device)
    }


    //looking at all device objects and asking for list of asset tags
    for thisDevice in realm.objects(Device.self) {
        print("\(thisDevice.asset_tags)")
    }
```

**SECOND EDIT**

This is not the way I would do it but I think this is what you might find easier to understand.

```
    class AssetTags: Object { 

        dynamic var id = 0

        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
        }

        dynamic var tagValue = ""
    }

    class Device: Object {   

        let assetTags = List<AssetTags>()

     }
```

So now Device has a list of asset tags. I added a primary id for Asset Tags because you indicated you might want to add more properties so an id should help make each one unique. It is optional though, so you can remove it if you do not need it.

To add assetTags objects to a Device object in a for-loop style (note: *device* in this code exampl is the device object you want to save the asset tags to):

```
    var assetTagArray: [String] = ["1", "2"]

    let realm = try! Realm()

    for assetTag in assetTagArray {

    let newAssetTag = AssetTags()

    newAssetTag.tagValue = assetTag

    newAssetTag.id = (realm.objects(AssetTags.self).max(ofProperty: "id") as Int? ?? 0) + 1

    do {

        try realm.write {

            device?.assetTags.append(newAssetTag)

        }

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

        return

    }

    }
```

Comment: Is this a negative of using Realm instead of core data? Is it easier to loop through arrays and insert into attributes with Core Data?

Comment: It is not really a negative. It is just how Realm works and it is better in my opinion compared to Core Data. There is an alternative way I could have shown you where you loop and enter data into Realm but the solution I gave you is best practice. Normally, you should use a higher order function like map instead of a for-loop because it is faster so that is what I gave you. If you are thinking Realm vs Core Data, stick to Realm. Realm is faster and much more thread safe.

Comment: You might want to read this to understand more on why I use map instead of a for loop https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/simple-higher-order-functions-in-swift-3-0-map-filter-reduce-and-flatmap-984fa00b2532. I know you wanted a loop, I could have given you one, but the solution I gave you is the best way to do things even if it looks a little intimidating at first.

Comment: Yes it looks very difficult. My only concern is I want to start with asset tag data but I will be adding other attributes that I would like to pull array into and I don't know if I can re-produce what you did for multiple attributes in my entity.

Comment: I have made it a bit easier for you. In my second edit please see a for loop way of doing things.

Comment: Even if I am using a to-one relationship do I still need to use a List to upload the array to Realm?

Comment: Yes indeed. So long as you intend to create a collection or an array of any kind in Realm, you need to use a List.

Comment: I am not trying to add an array into Realm, I am trying to take an array of values and loop through each value and add each value into Realm as a separate record in an attribute. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by a separate record in an attribute. I feel I might have misunderstood what you were asking. I think the best thing for you to do is to ask a new question on Stack where I or anyone else can answer. Add code samples of anything you've tried and/or illustrations of what you are trying to achieve. Be specific with your question to avoid down votes and I'm pretty sure you'll find the right answer you are looking for.